# Why do people set their tmux prefix to ctrl-a

Tags: tmux

I recently find this wonderful tool TMUX and playing with its configuration. Many people suggest to set prefix to ctrl-a, is it conflict with jump to the beginning of the current command ? 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/45521/how-to-navigate-long-commands-faster

Do I missing anything here? What is the advatange of changing it other than 'a' is closer than 'b'? 
Thanks

Comment: `^a` is from GNU `screen` ... I personally find `^b` to be at an awkward location to reach comfortably, and use `^p` (leftover from BSD `window` days). YMMV... Any conflicts can be resolved by using the prefix key twice (ie. `^a ^a`)

Comment: you should map caps-lock to ctrl, then using ctrl + a as prefix, you would find a new world.

Comment: press ctrl + a twice would jump to the begin of line in Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people use ctrl + A because they are used to the operations in `screen` which is another virtual terminal application.  They encourage people migrate from `screen` to `tmux` and provide a seamless way for the transition.  You can actually set up whatever way you like.

Comment: It also does not interfere with vim's ctrl + b to scroll backwards on your files

Comment: `C-a` is probably the best, the only issue you may encounter may be Ctrl - a (move to the beginning of the current line), simply use fn + ctrl (^) + a to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

Why ctrl-a as prefix, i think because it is easy for input and there is few confliction.
ps: you can press ctrl-a and then ctrl-b for jumping to the beginning of current line